# vbscript won't return multidimensional array

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

This is really getting annoying.  The following is a method which is contained in a custom database class.  I query data into a recordset then try to convert this data into an array w/o field names.  It appears to be working within the function because I setup a `response.write` to check if there were any values.  But once out of the function, things go haywire (the array is not the same).

```
Public Function To2Array()
    dim A, x, columns
    columns = Rs.Fields.Count
    Rs.MoveFirst()
    x = 0
    do until Rs.EOF
        Redim A(x+1,columns)
        for y = 0 to columns - 1
            A(x,y) = Rs.Fields.Item(y)
                            response.write A(x,y) 'returns correct value
        Next
        x = x + 1       
        Rs.MoveNext()
    loop
    To2Array = A
End Function
```

I assign the return array but there appears to be nothing.

```
arr = db.To2Array()
response.write(arr(1,0)) 'returns nothing
```

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can only grow the last dimension of an VBScript array. So you
   need an colsXrows array.
2. To keep the 'old' part of a dynamic array, you must ReDim Preserve.
3. To get a two dimensional array from a recordset, use [.GetRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - and avoid all risks of 'rolling your own'.

Comment: Using `GetRows` is ideal. @annoying_squid Just to note that using `ReDim` in a loop should be avoided. If you really want to 'roll your own' then you could read the `RecordCount` and just `ReDim` once.. but `GetRows` is the much better option.

Comment: My mind is wired for C arrays.  @Andy why is `GetRows` better than rolling your own?

Comment: `GetRows` is purpose-made to retrieve records form a recordset into an array - in one go. Read the link Ekkehard provided, noting that by not providing the number of rows it will retrieve ALL the rows from the recordset.

Answer (score 1):

You lose the values in A every time you redim it. Using redim preserve prevents this, but you can only redim the last array dimension when you use preserve.